# how to set system to share wifi access only to SPECIFIC site on internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Is it possible to have all computers within wifi range to get access only to specific addresses from Internet.Open internet access not permitted but need to broadcast connection to  specific addresses with open internet access requiring logon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But it depends on how many users and routers you'll have, how much bandwidth you'll be using and how much money you want to spend on this.

**Radius based solution**.

- You may buy routers with radius authentication. (e.g. [Mikrotik](http://mikrotik.com), [Ubiquiti](http://www.ubnt.com/))
- Or use unofficial firmware for standard SOHO routers (e.g. [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com), [OpenWRT](http://www.openwrt.org))

Along with radius server

- You may built your own radius server (e.g. [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.info/))
- Or rent this service on internet (e.g. [Sputnik](http://www.sputnik.com/products/)),  [HotSpotSystem](http://www.hotspotsystem.com/))

**Proxy solution**

- You can build proxy server at gateway with authentication (e.g. http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Portal/Splash)
- You can buy wifi devices which have builtin hotspot capability. [Mikrotik Hotspot](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Hotspot)